# Array Dereferencing using php 5.3 and Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, php-5.3

I wrote a code like

```
@section('title',Lang::get('lang.nav'['homepage'][1])
```

code in my laravel blade file.

but since my customer payed web hosting for a year and those idiots do not upgrade php version to 5.4 
I have to assimilate that code to php 5.3 but when I try like

```
{{$title=Lang::get('lang.nav')}}
{{$title['homepage'][1]}}
```

first it echoes the title then it gives error **array to string conversation**

so I need something like `\{{}}`  (do not echo just define the variable) 
so in the second part I can use it on the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline PHP as a workaround.

```
<?php $title =  Lang::get('lang.nav'); ?>
@section('title', $title['homepage'][1])
```